# How can one join the Royal Society of Chemistry as an AMRSC (or MRSC) without a referee?

Tags: united-states, professional-association, chemistry

The Royal Society of Chemistry (RSC) is an amalgam of what used to be many different societies, and has a long and rich history going back to Faraday (who incidentally, never received any degree), and it is considered a learned society, like the ACS in the USA, of which I am a long-standing member.

I have perused the RSC website extensively and I possess the necessary education and experience to join as a Associate Member, but one of the requisites when completing the application is that I name a referee, optimally someone who is already a member.

I do not know anyone who is a member as I live in the U.S.A. and simply have not crossed paths with such a person who would know me well enough.  I am aware there are offices in the US (Philadelphia) and there is not categorical statement that you must be of a certain nationality, so how do "Americans" apply?

Does anyone know how this process works?

Comment: Well, if having a referee is one of the requirements, then the answer to "how can one join without a referee?" is simply "one can't".  Maybe your real question is "how do I find a referee?"

Comment: If the application says "optimally someone who is already a member" perhaps they would accept as referee a senior member of the ACS who knows you and your work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [help page](http://www.rsc.org/help-legal/help/#membership) of the Royal Society of Chemistry:

> **Who can be a referee for my membership application?**
>
> Preferably a member of the Royal Society of Chemistry, however if you
>   do not know a member who can act as referee, a member of a similar
>   professional body can provide a reference. In some cases, a reference
>   from a senior colleague, for example, your line manager or head of
>   department will be acceptable.